# Make Java getAbsolutePath() return forward-slash on all machines

Tags: java, filenames, backslash

On Windows, `File::getAbsolutePath()` will return backward-slashes in paths; on UNIX, forward-slashes.

Since both versions are valid filenames on Windows machine, is it possible **to force** `File::getAbsolutePath()` (and associated functions) **to always return the *forward-slash* version** of a filename?

Comment: Why? If Windows is happy with `c:\foo\bar\baz.txt`, why force this to contain `/`?

Comment: Because the filenames are later processed by a "bash-compatible" tokenizer in order to execute a system command. This tokenizer uses `\` to escape special chars. I thus have to manually replace all `\` to `/` in the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function like `replaceAll()` to replace any backward-slash in the path by forward-slashes. This would look like :

```java
String oldPath = "path\\dzq\\dzqf";
String newPath = old.replaceAll("\\", "/");
```

More info on `replaceAll()` here : https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall and here : https://howtodoinjava.com/java/string/java-string-replaceall-example/

The functions returning you the path always use the platform's default separator : https://www.journaldev.com/851/java-file-separator-separatorchar-pathseparator-pathseparatorchar

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is what I'm currently doing. But I wanted to avoid having to wrap all calls to `getAbsolutePath()`, so ideally I wanted to know if I can force the method itself to do the replacement, for example by setting the path separator char.

Comment: @LaurentGrégoire You could "override" (between quotation marks because I'm not actually talking about `@Override`) the methods with others which just call the firsts, and then replace the slashes. Would that solve it ?

Comment: No, I've got calls to `getAbsolutePath()` scattered all around, and I wanted to avoid changing the code everywhere. "Overriding" would need to replace every call by my own code. Never mind, I'll go that way if it's not possible otherwise.